# Undefined references: cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list and cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list_buf_size

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to compile a code in Cygwin and I am receiving undefined reference error for "cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list" and "cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list_buf_size".

Is there any missing library that I should add? I am sure that win32 api packages are installed.

Thank you for your help.

```
tclEnv.o:tclEnv.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list_buf_size'
tclEnv.o:tclEnv.c:(.text+0xf6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list_buf_size'
tclEnv.o:tclEnv.c:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list'
tclEnv.o:tclEnv.c:(.text+0x118): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list'
/usr/bin/ld: tclEnv.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:550: recipe for target 'libtcl8.5.dll' failed
make: *** [libtcl8.5.dll] Error 1
```

Comment: What version of Cygwin are you using? The latest documentation has no reference to this function. Ref: http://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions were part of Cygwin 1.x, but [were removed in Cygwin 2.x](http://gdb-patches.sourceware.narkive.com/bmZUBSBu/rfa-2-2-remove-old-cygwin1-5-support).

Therefore we have to make some utility functions that utilizes new functions from version 2, but keeps the same name and interface (an adapter). As I needed to use some [code made in 2006](http://www.davehylands.com/Software/Open/) I also need to accomplish this. So let's start by looking at the documentation ...

- [API docs on Cygwin 1.4](http://pipeline.lbl.gov/code/3rd_party/licenses.win/cygwin-doc-1.4/html/cygwin-api/func-cygwin-posix-to-win32-path-list.html)
- [API docs for current Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/func-cygwin-conv-path.html)

This is the function definition for the current function for converting paths

`ssize_t cygwin_conv_path(
    cygwin_conv_path_t what, 
    const void * from, 
    void * to, 
    size_t size
);`

This is the function definition for the previous function for converting paths

`void cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list(const char *posix, char * win32);`

Using this and the example ([from the official docs](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/func-cygwin-conv-path.html)), we can probably make something work.

```
/**
 * Adapter for old Cygwin 1.x functions missing from Cygwin 2.x
 *
 * Based on the documentation for 1.4 and 2.x
 * - http://pipeline.lbl.gov/code/3rd_party/licenses.win/cygwin-doc-1.4/html/cygwin-api/func-cygwin-posix-to-win32-path-list.html
 * - https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/func-cygwin-conv-path.html
 *
 */
#include <sys/cygwin.h>

void cygwin_posix_to_win32_path_list(const char *posix, char * win32){

    // We do not know the size of the win32 buffer, but hopefully
    // it is at least size long ...
    ssize_t size = cygwin_conv_path( CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_A, posix, NULL, 0);

    cygwin_conv_path( CCP_POSIX_TO_WIN_A, posix, win32, size);
}
```

There are many ways to use this to fix your code:

- copy-paste into the code
- save into adapter.c and `#include adapter.c` in the relevant code
- compile it into adapter.o and link it to the other object files using `ld`